# grails portlet pagination on Liferay

Tags: grails, pagination, liferay

How to implement pagination in grails portlet on Liferay. 
The basic pagination was not working on Liferay. When clicked on next the page is jumping from Liferay url to normal url

I used like this :

```
<g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back"
        maxsteps="10" controller="book"
        action="list" total="${Book.count()}" />
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The normal pagination tag won't work inside a portlet, you'll need to copy the tag code and modify it to post to the actionURL of your portlet (call the jsp tag provided by the portal to get this url from your gsp tag code), instead of the default url for the controller.

I've never done this myself, someone else my be able to post some example code.

cheers

Lee

Comment: Hi leebutts,
Could you please go through this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272120/grails-portlets-deployment-on-liferay

I need some help on this ...

thanks.