# Grails portlets deployment Issue

Tags: deployment, grails, liferay

I'm running one grails portlet on liferay 5.2.3 successfully, now i developed another grails portlet and hot deployed, but the portlet showed me some errors and not working says "portlet is temporarily available" .

I tried restart server but still only one portlet is running and other is not running .

This is the log when deployed another portlet (log cropped).

**10-02-16 19:36:59:484 - { INFO} com.liferay.portal.plugin.PluginPackageUtil Finished checking for available updates in 63 ms

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.container.AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.getInstance(AbstractPortletContainerAdapter.java:27)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.initPortletContainerAdapter(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.grails.portlets.GrailsPortletApplicationContext.setPortletContext(GrailsPortletApplicationContext.java:28)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.createPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletApplicationContext(FrameworkPortlet.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.initPortletBean(FrameworkPortlet.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.GenericPortletBean.init(GenericPortletBean.java:115)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.init(GenericPortlet.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.init(InvokerPortletImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:853)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
10-02-16 19:37:02:333 - {ERROR} portal-web.docroot.html.portal.render_portlet.jsp java.lang.NullPointerException**

Could any one tell me whats going wrong and how can we run multiple grails portlets on Liferay.

thanks in advance .

Comment: Hi, I saw your question but can't help sorry. I've never done any development on Liferay. Have you tried the Grails User mailing list?

Comment: No, i opened this in jira.codehaus.org 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1967?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: OMG, i'm unable to open post in http://grails.markmail.org. I didn't found any link to create new thread. plz help me